# Integration of Jfrog Artifactory with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, artifactory

From last couple of days i'm trying to integrate Jfrog Artifactory with Postgressql Server.But I'm Faling to integrate.we followed the Jfrog Documentation still its using Derby database.

Can anyone please help me.Thanks in Advance.

we have conan packages of 10GB+ thats why we want to integrate JFrog with Posgresql.

Comment: Please share more information on the exact steps you performed to migrate from derby to postrgresql. Please note that by default Artifactory does not store the binaries inside the database, but rather store them on the file system. You can configure Artifactory to store the binaries in the database but it is not recommended. Switching from Derby to PostgreSQL will not help you to deal better with large binaries. It will help of you need to manage large numbers of binaries

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/PostgreSQL to use PostgreSQL.
As the Artifactory is still connected to Derby, maybe `db.properties` is not changed to point to the PostgreSQL DB.
Make sure you take a backup of current `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/db.properties` and change the `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/db.properties` to point to the PostgreSQL DB and add the correct JDBC driver file in `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/tomcat/lib` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kashif.I followed the same documentation   with Jfrog CE C++ Community edition and its still using Derby database.Is it possible to integrate jfrog CE C++ community Edition with Postgresql?